# For what p does $\sum_{k=2}^\infty = \frac{1}{k^2\ln^pk}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am not sure how to to it and if my approach is correct.

With the integral test I can show that $$\sum_{k=2}^\infty = \frac{1}{k\ln^pk}$$ converges for all $p> 1$, but what about 
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty = \frac{1}{k^2\ln^pk}$$ ?

Can I use the comparison test as $\sum_{k=2}^\infty = \frac{1}{k^2\ln^pk} < \sum_{k=2}^\infty = \frac{1}{k\ln^pk}$ and then say that it also converges for all $p > 1$?

Also, how do I find $p$ if I write $ \sqrt{k} $ instead of $k^2 $? For this I am not sure how to start, I would appreciate a hint.

Comment: It converges for all $p$. Integral test works fine, but the main intuition is that $\log k$ grows so slow that it is eventually beaten by $k^{\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

For all $p$, it converges due to the [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test):

$$\frac1{n^2\ln^pn}\to\frac{2^n}{(2^n)^2\ln^p2^n}=\frac1{2^nn^p\ln^p2}$$

Which converges for all $p$.

Comment: Note that $\frac1{n^2\ln^pn}\to0$ for all $p$, so it is eventually a non-increasing sequence.

Comment: @DonAntonio Ok, my bad, it is monotonically decreasing for $n>1$ if $p\ge0$ and $n>e^{-p/2}$ if $p<0$.